# Is it good or bad to specify controller in templates only?

Tags: angularjs

I found myself annoyed when I need to specify which controller to use for a template every time I use it for a route or a directive. It get worse when template coupled to a controller with `controllerAs` syntax, and I have to remember which name it has to be.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'stateTemplate.html',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  controller: 'StateController'
});

ngDialog.open({
    template: 'stateTemplate.html',
    controller: "StateController",
    controllerAs:"ctrl"
});
```

I’d rather prefer to specify `ng-controller StateController as ctrl` in the template and totally skip `controller` and `controllerAs` in the other places.

The question is: does this approach has some pitfalls I don’t see now? Why it's bad (if it is)? Are the benefits of explicit `controller` and `controllerAs` parameters against using `ng-controller` in the corresponding template? Where canI learn more about it?

Comment: By putting the controller as in the template you introduce business logic into the template = bad. For example you can't change which controller you're using without editing the template now (whereas controller as in the state logic means you can swap them out without editing the template as long as the interface is the same)

Comment: You won't be able to use resolve anymore. I find it quite strange that you're using the same controller and the same template for different routes, or for a route and a dialog. Why is that?

Comment: Probably should look at upgrading to ui router for more flexibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of people are misunderstanding your question. Am I correct in paraphrasing it as:

What is wrong with only defining a view in your Route Config and then binding that view to a controller using `ng-controller="StateController as ctrl"`?

So instead of your examples above you would have:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'stateTemplate.html',
});

ngDialog.open({
    template: 'stateTemplate.html',
});
```

Then in your `stateTemplate.html` you would have something like:

```
<div ng-controller="StateController as ctrl">
    <h1>State</h1>
    . . .
</div>
```

Is this what you are asking?

If so, nothing is wrong with this. You will lose the ability to reuse controllers with different views. But honestly that might not be a real concern.

If you use `bindToController` in directives (you should) you will still want to declare the controller in the Directive Data Object rather than use `ng-controller`. `bindToController` causes the property to be bound to the controller before the controller is instantiated.

The other thing you will lose out on is controller dependancy resolve objects.

With `uiRouter` and `ngRouter` you can use a resolve object that will then get passed into the controller when the dependancies are resolved. For instance you do not want to display the user details page until the call to get the user details has been returned. Once it is returned it can be passed into the constructor of the controller. This is another thing you will lose out on using with `ng-controller`. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#resolving-promises-for-a-controller

I am sure there are other benefits to using the declared controllers in the route config. Maybe someone else will point them out.

That said, there is nothing wrong with using it. You should probably be consistent with it so that your code is predictable. If you choose to use `ng-controller`, it may not not be a big deal to change it in the future. Especially if you have protractor web tests set up so that you know you haven't broken anything.

Comment: Thank you @Martin for bringing a sense to my question! That's exactly I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest answer - bad.

You cannot define business logic inside controller template. What if you need to use now 30 different controllers? are you going to specify 30 different controllers? It's messy, it's unadvised and it's a bad practice all together.

It's like writing BLL inside the input logic layer, or authentications in client side code. You are just making it hard on yourself here.

Defining controllers in templates is defiantly not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: He is not asking if the controller should be part of the template, he is asking if it is OK to bind the template to the controller using ng-controller rather than in the route config. Business logic should not live in controllers. Controllers should be for presentation logic.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, it was a bit confusing.